# How to send a messag to multiple recipients in (a)Smack?

Tags: smack

I am wondering if there is a way to set multiple targets for a message instead of sending message to multiple targets separately?

```
 for(i = 0; i<x ; i++){

Message msg = new Message("reza@myhostMessage.Type.chat);
   msg.setBody("HEY");
    try {
        connection.sendPacket(msg);
    } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`MultiRecipientManager.send(XMPPConnection connection, Packet packet, List<String> to, List<String> cc, List<String> bcc)`](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/address/MultipleRecipientManager.html#send(org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection,%20org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet,%20java.util.List,%20java.util.List,%20java.util.List))

Comment: Depends if your service supports "Extended Stanza Addressing", if yes, then only one stanza will be send, if not, then the fallback is to send multiple stanzas.

Comment: That is also very clearly stated in the javadoc of the mentioned method: " If the server has support for XEP-33 then only one packet is going to be sent to the server with the multiple recipient instructions. However, if XEP-33 is not supported by the server then the client is going to send the packet to each recipient."

Comment: Hello @Flow Need some help in Chat App using smack with openfire.