# asmack send message to a rouster group

Tags: xmpp, smack

I want to send a message to a roster Group (like friends group) by using asmack.(i dont want to create a room using multi user chat)

Asmach has this :

```java
 Message msg=new Message(java.lang.String to, Message.Type type)
```

when want to a single user i use : Message("a@b.com",Message.Type.chat)

but in group chat I think I have to use Message(java.lang.String to, Message.Type.groupchat) but I don't know what **java.lang.String to** should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP does not specifiy a mechanism to send a message to a roster group. But you can easily implement that on your own. Just collect all the JIDs, and eventually all presences, of the roster group and send the message to every one of them (preferably with Smack's [MultipleRecpientManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503960/how-to-send-a-messag-to-multiple-recipients-in-asmack)).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to send message to all the roster group members in following way. You can try it.

---

**The method that sends message to multi-users in a group**

```
/**
 * Sends Group message
 *
 * @param message
 * @param groupName
 * @throws XMPPException
 * @throws SmackException.NotConnectedException
 */
public void sendGroupMessage(String groupName, String message) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, XMPPException {
    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
    RosterGroup rosterGroup = roster.getGroup(groupName);
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = rosterGroup.getEntries();
    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
       String user = entry.getName();
       System.out.println(String.format("Sending message " + message + " to user " + user));
        Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(user, messageListener);
        chat.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

---

**The calling method**

```
classNameOfYourMethod.sendGroupMessage(groupName, groupMessage);
```

if you need classification ask in comment.

Comment: in receiving end how you recognize this is a group message ? this will receive as an individual message.

Comment: exactly i am iterating on the rooster and then delivering the message for every user in the group. It is not possible to send group message in smack. So it was the only way out.

Comment: maybe its Broadcast message.