# Send message to all users inside a group - Smack API

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I know that we can privately chat with the users in a group by `Chat chat = muc2.createPrivateChat("myroom@conference.jabber.org/johndoe");
chat.sendMessage("Hello there");` as given in the documentation.

But I didn't find a way to publicly chat to all the users in the group. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as i understand it , you can use roster group and collect roster group ids and send them all this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577909/asmack-send-message-to-a-rouster-group

Comment: what exactly it's the meaning of "publicly chat to all users in the group" ? What is the "group" you are referring? Why do you create a Chat and not a MultiUserChat? Why do you create a Private Chat and you want to publicy it? please explain better

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for comments on my question. I solved by problem of chatting to all the users in the group as follows,

```
Message msg = new Message("mychattingroom@conference.10.10.1.105", Message.Type.groupchat);
msg.setBody("Hai... How are you?..");
oXmppConnection.sendPacket(msg);
```